# How to resize DragShadowBuilder?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a `DragShadowBuilder` on longClick on an `ImageView`.

```
    val data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "")
    dragShadow = MyDragShadowBuilder(imageViewTemp, imageLayout.width, imageLayout.width)
    imageViewTemp.startDragAndDrop(data, dragShadow, imageViewTemp, View.DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE)
```

As you can see, I have set the width and height of the `DragShadowBuilder`, but I want to resize it to 250, when it will be dragged. How can I do that? If I can't resize it, Can I recreate the `DragShadowBuilder` with some reduced width and height?

```
class MyDragShadowBuilder(
    view: View,
    val scaledWidth: Int,
    val scaledHeight: Int
) : View.DragShadowBuilder(view) {
    var tempScaleX = 0.0F
    var tempScaleY = 0.0F

    override fun onProvideShadowMetrics(outShadowSize: Point?, outShadowTouchPoint: Point?) {
        // calculate the scaled view's dimensions
        tempScaleX = scaledWidth.toFloat() / view.width
        tempScaleY = scaledHeight.toFloat() / view.height

        // set the scaled shadow size
        outShadowSize?.set(scaledWidth, scaledHeight)

        // re-center the out touch point using the scaled dimensions
        outShadowTouchPoint?.set(scaledWidth / 2, scaledHeight / 2)
    }

    override fun onDrawShadow(canvas: Canvas?) {
        // scale the canvas so it can fit the scaled view
        canvas?.scale(
            tempScaleX,
            tempScaleY
        )

        view.draw(canvas)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 250 dp or something else?

Comment: The constructor of MyDragShadowBuilder only takes Integer. So, it means 250 only.

Comment: class MyDragShadowBuilder(
    view: View,
    val scaledWidth: Int,
    val scaledHeight: Int
) : View.DragShadowBuilder(view) {
    var tempScaleX = 0.0F
    var tempScaleY = 0.0F

    override fun onProvideShadowMetrics(outShadowSize: Point?, outShadowTouchPoint: Point?) {
        tempScaleX = scaledWidth.toFloat() / view.width
        tempScaleY = scaledHeight.toFloat() / view.height

        outShadowSize?.set(scaledWidth, scaledHeight)

        outShadowTouchPoint?.set(scaledWidth / 2, scaledHeight / 2)
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add the `MyDragShadowBuilder` source code. It would be more readable and helpful for me & others.